# Pyinstaller: Is there a way to package apps for Windows and Linux on MacOS (or vice versa)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller, python-packaging

I packaged a kivy app on MacOS and I'm trying to port it to Windows and Linux. Didn't see anything in the pyinstaller docs so I tried using VirtualBox to run pyinstaller in Windows and Linux virtual environments. It didn't work on Windows because I for some reason couldn't call python in command prompt. Didn't try it on Linux yet because I wanted to know if I'm just wasting my time.

Comment: On any freshly minted OS installed from an ISO into a VM you need to ensure that base components for your requirements are install.  For example on Ubuntu 20.04, to meet my requirements, I install `linux-headers build-essentials git python3-venv python3-pip` to meet my python runtime needs.   It's no different on cloud envs (AWS, GCloud, Azure) it's just base build will differ

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this kind of stuff so that really helps!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when you're installing python on a Windows VM you have to install it to PATH